# WCF WIF token could not be authenticated or authorized

Tags: wcf, wif

I have a MVC site that athenticates with an STS and then calls a webservice.

I'm opening the channel using the token just fine but i get the following error on a method call.  I'm using the ws2007federatedbindings and have tried every example i could find all resulting in the same error.  I have validate the token is issued correctly for the service, at least 99% sure.  =)

> {"ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or
>   authorized."}

When i enable tracing, I do find these message, but I'm not sure where to even start looking.

This warning in the WCF service

> The configuration system has detected a duplicate key in a different configuration scope and is overriding with the more recent value.

This error in the WCF service

> Message security verification failed.

This error in the MVC trace

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.
>   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

**EDIT**

It appears that the audienceUris is case sensitive.  =/

I'm still trying to figure out what the duplicate key in different configuration scope warning means but I no longer get the ID3242 error and it delegates to the wcf service correctly.  Dominick Baier has been super helpful in figuring it out.  I recommend his blog http://www.leastprivilege.com/